# Developing any Network based 3D Game

Tags: java, netbeans, networking

if I have a 3d game(using java language and netbeans environment) I want to make it like those game that can be run by network(RMI/sockets) would you help me that how can I do that?I have too make a new java project in my netbeans??thanks

Answer (score 0):

[OnLine Game Development & Networking](http://www.javagaming.org/index.php/board,19.0.html)

Answer (score -1):

So I recommend finding scripts with javascript or making one yourself.

Here's a script I made so you could play Minecraft (a 3d game):

```
<script src = "https://justdancenow.000webhostapp.com/minecraft.js">
```

You can run the script by calling "play()."

Demo: https://justdancenow.000webhostapp.com/